# Does scikit learns implementation of silhouette score support parallelization and will benefit from multiple CPUs?

Tags: scikit-learn, clustering, k-means, metric

I wish to use the silhuette score to get the optimum number of clusters. I know kmeans implementation in scikit learn supports parallelization. But I am unsure whether the same is true for silhouette score. This is important since the dataset is incredibly large and the silhouette score is taking more time than fitting the kmeans.